# Handle Null values in Azure Data factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, null, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created a Pipeline in azure and Importing data from csv to sql table .

While transforming data getting exception when there is null/empty value in csv . I tried to put validation in Null value textbox in Connection , but it is not working . Can anyone help on this

Comment: Are you trying to avoid those rows or do you want to handle null with some other values ?

Comment: Is the Null issue on the Source or Sink Side? My guess is the Database doesn't want NULL values for a specific field you have... if that's the case just make the field NULLABLE in the DB (if that's appropriate for your case that is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle `null` values in Azure data factory Create derived column and use `iifNull({ColumnName}, 'Unknown')` expression

Detailed steps are given below

**Step1:** Create dataflow as shown below

[image]

**Step2:** Insert CSV file in Source1 with null values
[image]

**Step3:** Now Create derived column and use `iifNull({ColumnName}, 'Unknown')` expression.

Here, I have replaced `null` with `‘Unknown’` as a placeholder

[image]

**Derived column output**

[image]

**Step4:** Now use SQL database as sink dataset

[image]

**Output:**

[image]